# Google Direction service giving wrong route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, directions

Drawing googlemap route on map with below coordinates.But getting wrong route.  Where is the issue?

```
LNG                    LAT
58.5589893333333       23.6229513333333   Start
58.5589985             23.6231225         WAY POINT 1
58.5591366666667       23.6235491666667   WAY POINT 2
58.55882               23.6236481666667   WAY POINT 3
58.5476361666667       23.6209141666667   WAY POINT 4
58.5454098333333       23.616038          END
```

the wrong route

[image]

Same coordinates tried in Google map website,It is giving correct way

[image]

Where is the problem? Sending all the waypoints, origin and destination correctly. The coordinates are from tracking devices. only some cases showing wrong route like this.

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();     
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
var first = new google.maps.LatLng(23.6231225,58.5589985);
var second = new google.maps.LatLng(23.6235491666667,58.5591366666667);
var third = new google.maps.LatLng(23.6236481666667,58.55882);
var forth = new google.maps.LatLng(23.6209141666667,58.5476361666667); 
var i = 0;
var start = StartlatDir[i]+','+StartlongDir[i];
var end = EndlatDir[i] + ',' + EndlongDir[i];
var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: [{ location:first, stopover: false },
        { location: second, stopover: false },
        { location: third, stopover: false },
        { location: forth, stopover: false }],
    optimizeWaypoints: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
};
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var myRoute = response.routes[0];
        var txtDir = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
            txtDir += myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].instructions + "<br />";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What are `StartlatDir[i]`, `StartlongDir[i]`, `EndlatDir[i]` &`EndlongDir[i]`?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The start values are 58.5589893333333       23.6229513333333   

End values are 58.5454098333333       23.616038

Comment: Please [edit] your question to address comments.

Comment: @user6753632 did you find any solution for ths.

Answer (score 0):

The DirectionsService is very sensitive to waypoints near exits (or on the wrong side of the road).

Waypoint 4 `(23.6209141666667, 58.5476361666667)` makes the route take the exit.

[image: original route]

Moving it further along the road to `(23.620315,58.5471)` gives the expected route:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4ewsjr0x/2/)

[image: map with waypoint 4 after the exit]
or removing it completely gives the expected route

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4ewsjr0x/1/)

[image: map with waypoint 4 removed]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time...Here the issue is I cannot edit the way points or remove the way points...All points are getting from vehicle tracking device...Here I took few location data as example to describe the problem easily.....So we are facing this  type of issue in routes in different road  with different gprs data ..........can I ask, Will Snap to road functionality solve this this issue?And Is it possibe to animate a vehicle through snap to road route like   https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/dk1zp2n8/     ?

Comment: Snap to road might solve the issue, it might also have the same issue (as it uses the same underlying data).  Have you tried it?  Once you get the correct route you want you should be able to do animation like that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/dk1zp2n8/)

Comment: Snap to road will make other issues..It will success only when locations are very near....  Please see this link with the same coordinates..why the route is not showing till the end point ..I am not sure  ......        https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/roads/full/inspector_with_api_key#23.6229513333333,58.5589893333333|23.6231225,58.5589985|23.6235491666667,58.5591366666667|23.6236481666667,58.55882|23.6209141666667,58.5476361666667|23.616038,58.5454098333333

Comment: Each Location data will snap to road first then call direction request with snapped points?Will it solve issue?And any idea how to snap to road only one point (lat,lon)   and   how to get this snapped location data?